# Parallelise 'for' loop reading and writing to data structure with Open MP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I'm using C++ to create a finite element analysis routine, and I'm trying to use Open MP to parallelise some 'for' loops in my code.

I have an array of structures called Elements, with each section of the array containing a structure with all of the information for that particular element. Some of the information that is required is a stiffness matrix for each element (called kt in the code below). This is then assembled into a global stiffness matrix for the whole system.

The calculation of the element stiffness matrix is pretty involved and lengthy so I reckon I could get some good speed gains by parallelising its calculation.

The below code works fine when everything related to Open MP is commented out but fails when it isn't despite the fact that I am not writing to Elements at the same time and kt and Elementsi (the ith element) are private to the thread they are being used in.

I'm using Armadillo for the matrix algebra so that is what the 'mat' means.

I'm pretty new to C++ so any help will be much appreciated.

```
mat KtCalc(struct Element Elements[],mat Nodes,double ngamma,double nbeta,double hhtalpha, int nel, double dt)
//Stiffness matrix calculation routine
{
    int nn=Nodes.n_rows;
    mat Kt(nn*6, nn*6, fill::zeros);
    int i;
    struct Element Elementi;
    mat kt;
   #pragma omp parallel private(Elementi,kt) shared(nel,i,hhtalpha,ngamma,nbeta,dt,Elements)
    {

    #pragma omp for
    for(i=0;i<nel;i++)
        {
            #pragma omp critical(dataupdate)
            {
            Elementi=Elements[i];
            }
            kt=KtEl(Elementi, ngamma, nbeta, hhtalpha,  dt);
            #pragma omp critical(dataupdate)
            {
            Elements[i].kt=kt;
            }
        }
}
    for(int k=0;k<nel;k++){
        //Use the stuff calculated above in a non parallel way to calculate Kt

    }
    return Kt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was the shared deceleration of the `i` of the forloop. In cpp you're allowed to declare variables anywhere. The following code is equivalent and should work:

```
mat KtCalc(struct Element Elements[],mat Nodes,double ngamma,double nbeta,double hhtalpha, int nel, double dt)
//Stiffness matrix calculation routine
{
    int nn=Nodes.n_rows;
    mat Kt(nn*6, nn*6, fill::zeros);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<nel;i++)
    {
        Elements[i].kt=KtEl(Elements[i], ngamma, nbeta, hhtalpha,  dt);
    }
    for(int k=0;k<nel;k++){
        //Use the stuff calculated above in a non parallel way to calculate Kt

    }
    return Kt;
}
```

Also, you're allowed to modify the elements of an array simultaneously, as long as you're sure you're never modifying the same element (which is the case as you're only touching the `i`th element). The `critical` sections where thus unnecessary.

On a side note, you'd generally want your variables to be declared as late as possible. Declaring them on top is old c style. Declaring them as late as possible [means](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56585/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them):

- It makes RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) easier.
- It keeps the scope of the variable tight. This lets the optimizer work better.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer does compile, but it doesn't run. If I comment out the #pragma line then it works fine. My original answer ran for one time step (in programming terms that means that this worked the first time it was called). Any ideas why that might be? I'm wondering if the linear algebra libraries are trying to do something in parallel in the background.

Comment: I don't think armadillo does any parallelization itself, calling armadillo should, however, be thread safe. The blas/lapack library you're using might however not be. Most of them should be thread safe, and some even do some of the parallelization themselves (openblas for instance). Did my 'improved' code return the same error? What kind of errors are you getting? Do you know what libraries (including versions) you're currently linking to?

Comment: Also, though I noticed the possible issue of explicitly declaring the `i` as shared, my experience with armadillo is rather limited, and this might unfortunately quickly become to advanced for me to help you.

Comment: If you're using it at all you're probably better than me so any help will be appreciated! Looks like I'm using LAPACK 3.2.1, I'm not sure about BLAS. I downloaded precompiled libraries from here http://ylzhao.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/blas-lapack-precompiled-binaries-for.html .

Comment: A bit of digging reveals that there is a non thread safe function pre LAPACK 3.3 that gets called by lots of other routines, including matrix solve. I'll look into replacing my libraries.

Comment: @PeterGreaves That might have very well been the culprit. Did you get it to work after upgrading to the newer threadsafe version?

Comment: No - that didn't do it either. I've realised I can just run the simulations as separate .exe files on different processors so it isn't really a problem! Thanks for your help though.